# jQuery fadeOut&fadeIn two images exactly at the same time with same speed

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I am developing one web dashboard, which I need to fadeOut fadeIn three divs, each div contains 2 images, sequentially.

I faced some issues

1. 2 images in each div would not fadeOut with same speed although I use the same code for both of them.
2. between fading out and fading in of 2 divs I have a white page.

In order to be more clear of my question I will attach one image from architecture of my HTML , and my jQuery function.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance

```js
// this jQuery as Demo
setTimeout(function(){
  // I expect to there 2 first fadeOut is done exactly togheter
    $("#img1").fadeOut(8000);
    $("#img2").fadeOut(8000);
  // I expect to these 2 fadeIn is done exactly togheter
    $("#img3").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#img4").fadeIn(2000);
    
},timeOutDuration);
  

};
```

```html
<div1 >
<img1 id="img1">
 <!-- This image is greater than img2 with lower z-index, because I want to use it as background  --> 
 </img1>
<img2 id="img2">
<!-- this image should be aligned to bottm left -->
</img2>
</div1>

<div2>
<img3 id="img3">
<!-- This image is greater than img4 with lower z-index, because I want to use it as background  -->  
</img3>
<img4 id="img4">
<!-- this image should be aligned to bottm left --> 
</img4>
</div2>

<div3>
<img5 id="img5">
<!-- This image is greater than img6 with lower z-index, because I want to use it as background  -->   
</img5>
<img6 id="img6">
<!-- this image should be aligned to bottm left -->    
</img6>
</div3>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxIh7.png)

Comment: Which value you gave to timeOutDuration ?

Comment: timeoutDuration=4000

Answer (score 0):

Call the first 2 fadeOut images in the same function then use the callback to set away the 2 fadeIns

```
$("#img1, #img2").fadeOut(8000, function(){
     $("#img3, #img4").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I really do not know why before fading in img3,I have a white page for some milliseconds.img4 perfectly fades in but img3 not.this is one of the issues which I have.Can you help in this issue?